# It is possible that both positive part and negative part of a measurable function to have integral equal to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a measure space. Let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. We know that $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$ where $f^{+}(x)=\sup\{f(x),0\} $ and $f^{-}(x)=\sup\{-f(x),0\}$.

My question is:

It is possible that $\int_{X} f^{+}d\mu=\int_{X} f^{-} d\mu = +\infty$ ? Or it is the case that if one of these integrals are infinity, the other is necessarily finite?

Comment: What about $f(x)=x$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$

Comment: So it is possible and the example is very simple. But what can we say about $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x d\lambda$ ? it is not finite, not $+\infty$ and not $-\infty$. So what it is?

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x d\lambda$ is not defined.

Comment: It's is very undesirable, this integral in particular should be $0$ since the negative and positve part are quite symetrical.

Comment: @VictorRafael: That's what the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is for.

Comment: very good to know the existence of the principal value, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is measurable, the integrability of $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ depends on $f$ itself and on the measure space of interest $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Indeed, **if** $\int_Xf^+d\mu,\,\int_Xf^-d\mu<\infty$ **then we define** (usually) the $\mu$-integral as $\int f d\mu := \int_Xf^+d\mu -\int_Xf^-d\mu$ and we say that $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ so it all rests on the condition that the two integrals are $<\infty$.

**Example.**

(1). *Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then $x \mapsto x$ is not integrable. Indeed it suffices to see that $\int_\mathbb{R}x^+d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{[0,n]}xd\lambda = \infty$ so the condition to define the $\mu$-integral is not met.*

(2). *Let $([-n,n],\mathcal{B}([-n,n]),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x \mapsto x$ is integrable.*

(3). *Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space and $u:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$. Let $\mu_u$ be the image measure of $u$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Then consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu_u)$. We have that $\int_\mathbb{R}x d\mu_u=\int_X u d\mu$ thus $x \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu_u)$.*

Recall that $u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ **if and only if** $|u| \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ so the 'cancellation' that $x \mapsto x$ on $\mathbb{R}$ would intuitively enjoy is disregarded.

Comment: It is common to also define the $\mu$-integral in the cases where one of $\int f^+$, $\int f^-$ is infinite and the other is finite, in which case the value of $\int f\,d\mu$ is taken to be either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ respectively.  However such a function $f$ is still said to be "not integrable" despite the fact that its integral exists (as an extended real number).